# Can Netbeans handle both 32-bit and 64-bit version of Java?

Tags: java, ide, netbeans, 64-bit, jvm

I'm running 64-bit version of Vista on my notebook with 4G of RAM, the Ram is maxed out at 1.5G on the 32-bit version of Java. But if I move completely to 64-bit version of Java, the JDIC part won't work, so my question is : if I install both 32 and 64 bit versions of Java, can Netbeans easily switch between the two ? So if I run out of ram at 1.5G, I switch to the 64-bit, but if I need to develop JDIC part, I switch back to the 32-bit, is this possible with Netbeans ?

========================================================================

I've just realized I asked half a question, since which version(32/64 bit) of Netbeans also matters. So my question should be : If I run 64-bit of Neatbeans(assume it's available), and have both versions of Java installed, can I switch between the two Java versions for my projects in Netbeans ?

Comment: If you want for Netbeans to take advantage of your 64-bit system, you need to install a 64-bit version of the Java Development Kit (JDK) for Windows 7. 
You can get the JDK from the Oracle web site: 
http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/index.html 
You should install the latest version if you can, which is now JDK SE 7u11 (same as 1.7.0_11). 

Netbeans runs as a Java application in the Java runtime. There is no OS-specific version for Windows, Linux, or Mac, etc. There is no hardware-specific version for 32-bit or 64-bit, etc.

Answer (score 3):

NetBeans does work with both 64-bit and 32-bit JVM.  Eclipse can only work with 32-bit JVM.  I have a script for launching Eclipse with installed 32-bit JVM and NetBeans for the 64-bit or 32-bit JVM.

Comment: I'm now running 32-bit NB, but if I run the 64-bit version, why do I need a script to launch different JVMs ? Can't I specify it inside the 64-bit NB ?

Comment: I have several JREs installed so the script simply sets the JAVA_HOME and such, no magic. :)

Answer (score 1):

You cannot switch JVMs in a running app. You'll have to restart it, but you should certainly be able to run Netbeans in both JVMs.

Comment: I was under the impression that he doesn't care what NetBeans itself is running in, but I could be wrong.

Comment: Does NetBeans use whatever JVM it's running in to run a project?

Comment: I read it as wanting to run Netbeans itself in differen JVMs. Of course it does not necessarily use the same JVM to run projects.

Comment: it matters more which JVM netbeans is running in. JDIC has native code parts (JNI) and JNI parts must match architecture. 32-bit jvm needs a 32-bit dll. 64bit jvm needs a 64bit dll. JDIC doesn't have a 64bit dll